# How to fix " No viable overloaded '=' " in C++

Tags: c++

This functions purpose is to put the individual lines of a .txt file into an array no bigger than 20. However, I don't know how to progress without being able to assign each line in my loop to that array.

```
int read_file(string file_name, person map[20], int 
line_limit)
{
    int line_count = 0;
    string x;
    person specific;
```

Btw the person class has 2 strings called first_name and last_name and 1 int named age. StackOverflow won't allow me to post the entire program I guess.

```
    fstream input_file;



    input_file.open(file_name, ios::in); 
    if (input_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "WORKING" << endl;
        //Loop through .txt file
        while (!input_file.eof() && line_count < 
line_limit)
        {
            if (input_file.good())
            {
                input_file >> x;
                map[line_count] = x;
```

The ABOVE line derives "No viable overloaded '=' " error.

```
                line_count++;
            }

        }
     }
    else
        cout << "Not Working" << endl;
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Any tips would also be great!

This is the .txt file I'm looping through. I want to assign each firs name, last name, and age as I loop through the .txt file. I want to assign it to string x and then put the what is in x at the time into the array that is type person that takes parameters string last_name, string first_name, and int age.

```
Ann Christensen  70
Carlos Morales   68
David Bowman     45
Frank Bowman     37
John Bowman      30
Kathleen Gueller 34
Mark Bowman      42
Mark Bowman      13
Richard Bowman   47
Susan Cox        36
```

```
class person
{



private:
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    int age;

//Person Constructor - Empty
public:
    person()
    {
        first_name = "";
        last_name = "";
        age = 0;

        //void get(istream &);
        //void put(ostream &);
        //bool operator = ();
}
```

Comment: A `string` is not a `person`, so what do you expect `map[line_count] = x;` to do?

Comment: I'm trying to assign the string x to the first_name, then last_name, then age as it loops through this .txt file.                                   
Ann Christensen  70
Carlos Morales   68
David Bowman     45
Frank Bowman     37
John Bowman      30
Kathleen Gueller 34
Mark Bowman      42
Mark Bowman      13
Richard Bowman   47
Susan Cox        36

Comment: I'll add the .txt file to the post if i can...

Comment: More relevant would be the definition of `person`, though what's stopping you from just doing something like `map[line_count].first_name = x;` (or using a setter if you have one)?

Comment: Would that work @UnholySheep or would I get the same = operator error? I'll try it though for sure.

Comment: It says it's a private member. I'll try to add the class to the post.

Comment: Ok added the person class.

Comment: You made a class that is immutable. You need to add setters to it if you want to modify any of the data it stores

Comment: I have never used one. I'll try to do some digging into that rn.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to assign a string into a position that should hold a `person` object. This attempts to do either 1, or, if that fails, goes on to 2.

1. Convert the string into a `person`, using a conversion that would be defined by the class `person`, which looks like `operator string()`
2. Assign the string to the `person` using a method `operator=(string)`. This must be defined in the `person` class.

Another option, since, what I think you're trying to do is to assign to a specific member, is to define a setter method. Usually, this would look like `set_first_name(string)`, if you are defining a setter for `first_name`, and would assign `first_name` to the accepted parameter. Basically, you just need some way to set `first_name` outside the class.

If you're assigning a string to another string, you won't get an `operator=` error. That only happens with user-defined classes.

Comment: The `operator string` in 1. does not work this way. It has to be an `operator person()` in the `string` class; however, the `string` class cannot be modified, as it is in the standard library. Alternatively create an implicit constructor `person(string)` in the `person` class.